# Summation of binomial coefficients multiplied by their index

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, geometric-progressions

> $\sum_{r=0}^{300}a_rx^r = (1+x+x^2+x^3)^{100}.$ If $a= \sum^{300}_{r=0}a_r$ then $\sum_{r=0}^{300}ra_r =?  $
>
> a) $300a$
>
> b) $100a$
>
> c) $150a$
>
> d) $75 a$

Attempt:

First of all if we substitute $x=1$, we get $a= 4^{100}$

Then, using formula of summation of geometric progression:

$\sum_{r=0}^{300}a_rx^r= (1-x^4)^{100}(1-x)^{-100}$

Using generalised binomial theorem, coefficient of $x^r$ in $(1-x)^{-100}$ is $\dbinom{99+r}{r}$ and that of $x^{4r}$ in $(1-x^4)^{100}$ is $(-1)^{100-r}\dbinom{n}{r}$

What do I do after this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been given

$$\sum_{r=0}^{300}a_rx^r = (1+x+x^2+x^3)^{100}$$

substitute $x = 1 $ to get $a = \sum a_r = 4^{100}$

Differentiate once w.r.t $x$ to get

$$\sum_{r=0}^{300}ra_rx^{r-1} = 100(1+x+x^2+x^3)^{99} (1+2x+3x^2)$$

again substitute $x = 1$ to get $\sum ra_r = 4^{99} \cdot 100  \cdot 6 = 150a$

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$f(x)=\sum_{r=0}^{300} a_rx^r=(1+x+x^2+x^3)^{100}$$
$$f'(x)=\sum_{r=0}^{300} ra_rx^{r-1}=100(1+x+x^2+x^3)^{99}(1+2x+3x^2)$$
$$f'(1)=\sum_{r=0}^{300} ra_r=600\cdot 4^{99}=150\cdot 4^{100}$$
We also have $$a=f(1)=\sum_{r=0}^{300} a_r=4^{100}$$

Comment: I thought someone will not post a similar answer and provide perhaps an alternative. Deeply disappointed.

Comment: @KingTut The method used is the most natural one which any person would think of because of the beauty of derivative lying inside the problem but I still apologise for a similar method

Comment: Ok I think you are correct. I also could think of another method.. if you discover anything please inform me, Thanks!

Comment: @KingTut Yep surely I will